# Non-negative, continuous function $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ that is unbounded?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification

I'm trying to construct a non-negative, continuous function $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\limsup\limits_{x\to \infty} f(x) = \infty.$ If someone could look over my attempt below, I would appreciate it!

---

Consider $$g_n(x) = \begin{cases}
  2n^4x-2n^5+n & \text{if $n-\frac{1}{2n^3}<x<n$}   \\
 -2n^4x+2n^5+n & \text{if $n \leq x<n+\frac{1}{2n^3}$} \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

My idea here was to construct a function with triangular bumps at each $n=1,2,3,...$ with height $n$ and base width $\frac{1}{n^3}$.
We note that the $g_n$ are continuous, non-negative and have support $[n-\frac{1}{2n^3}, n+\frac{1}{2n^3}]$. The supremum for each $g_n$ is $n$. Moreover, its integral is finite and given by $\frac{1}{2n^2}.$
Now, we consider the sum
$$G(x) :=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}g_n(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(2n^4x-2n^5+n)\chi_{(n-1/2n^3, n)}(x)+(-2n^4x+2n^5+n)\chi_{[n, n+1/2n^3)}(x)$$
We note that $G(x)$ is also continuous and non-negative. Its $L^1$ norm is given by $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{12}<\infty$$
so $G \in L^1.$ However, the heights of the function increase without bound, so we have that $\limsup\limits_{x\to \infty} f(x) = \infty.$

G(x) should look like this:
[image]

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: Same as above, but I will not check the explicit form you gave haha.

Comment: ^^No worries - thank you!

Comment: The graph looks piecewise linear while the function does not. But in principle, that's exactly how you construct such a function.

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo mixing up the exponents! I've fixed it.